# Spring boot 404 white label error when executing as Java application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a basic Spring Boot application created from Start.spring.io

Have the following package structure:
[image]

And the controller code is following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String test() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

When I execute this on an existing Tomcat server on my PC It is running succesfully.
But when I execute this as a Java Application from eclipse I get a 404 white label error

Comment: What is the url you try to access when running it from eclipse?

Comment: The URL would be http://localhost:8080/api/hello when you run it as java app

Comment: Yes I am Using localhost:8080/api/hello